# In case of server crash, queue data will be lost

Tags: java, file-upload

I'm working on creating file uploader. I would like to load files first temp folder and then convert them to needed format. For this I'll create a queue with tasks that will be executed with the executor. But in case of server crash, this queue will be lost. So could anybody suggest me a library without using another server that can make my queue persistent?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using in-memory queue implementation, you can use persistent options like DB or a JMS Queue. This will avoid loosing the data even if server crashes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use DB,a and store the bytes in it. Invoke 2 threads one will only feed the data to DB and another will poll onto convert the file. You can maintain the status if the file is changed to the format you wanted, and also the format it needs to be changed in